# Cannot configure a React Pre Hook with parameters passed to "npm start"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, package.json, npx

I have a brand new project created with:

```
$ npx create-react-app test-react-app && cd test-react-app && npm start
```

here the repo: https://github.com/tlg-265/test-react-app

I created a new script: `/prepare-project.js` with the following content:

```
let project = 'ferrari' // replace this value with the one passed via: $ npm start [what to put here?]

console.log(`########################`);
console.log(`###### The current project is: ${project} ######`);
console.log(`########################`);
```

The content of file: `/package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "test-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prestart": "node prepare-project.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

where you can see I configured the `pre hook`:

```
"prestart": "node prepare-project.js"
```

My goal is to run:

```
$ npm start [what to put here?]
```

so inside the script: `/prepare-project.js` I can read that value.

I tried with:

```
$ node prepare-project.js --project=mclaren
```

with no luck when trying to read that value from inside the script: `prepare-project.js`.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to put that value in a js file and pass to npm script. why don't you just put that in an environment `.env` file

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz because that value is not static and will change to whatever random value dynamicly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `yargs` module to parse command line arguments and then you can use `child_process` to execute your command. Here is what your code should look like, you may add your own custom logic.

```js
const yargs = require('yargs');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

const argv = yargs
    .option('project', {
        alias: 'p',
        description: 'name of the project',
        type: 'string',
    })
    .help()
    .alias('help', 'h')
    .argv;

console.log(argv.project);
console.log(`npm start --project=${argv.project}`);
const output = execSync(`npm start --project=${argv.project}`);
console.log(output)
```

Comment: that almost did the trick. When I run: `$ node prepare-project.js -p ford` it works well, but when I run: `$ npm start -p ford` then the script: `prepare-project.js` is not able to read the value of parameter: `project`. Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: even when I run: `$ npm run prestart --project=ford` the value of: `project` is `undefined`.

Comment: use `P=ford npm run prestart` and then access this `process.env.P`